# What is the equivalent probability of $P(X + Y = 11 | X=6)$?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let $X \sim Bin(10, .5)$, $Y \sim Bin(10, .5)$ and $X$, $Y$ are independent.

Which probability $P(X=6) \cdot P(Y=5)$, or $P(Y=5)$ (since X is given) is an equivalent probability of $P(X + Y = 10 | X=6)$ and why?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: With your notation, does the semicolon count as a logical "and" or as a "given that" conditional statement?

Comment: the semi colon is a 'given that' conditional.

Comment: Then it is simply $P(Y=5)$ since $X,Y$ are independent.

Comment: As an aside, you'll see that the people editing went and replaced the semicolon with the much more common $\mid$ to represent conditional probability.  I disagree with making that edit personally, as it could have been the notation specifically what was giving difficulty rather than the concepts.

Comment: There seems to be a typo. In the title you have $X+Y=11$, which matches the values $X=6$ and $Y=5$ in the body of the question. However, in the body you have $X+Y=10$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X+Y=10\mid X=6)&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(X+Y=10, X=6)}{\mathsf P(X=6)}&&\small\text{definition of conditional probability}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(Y=4, X=6)}{\mathsf P(X=6)}&&\small\text{obviously}\\[2ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(Y=4)\,\mathsf P(X=6)}{\mathsf P(X=6)}&&\small\text{independence of }X, Y\\[2ex]&=\mathsf P(Y=4)&&\small\text{cancelation}\end{align}$$

---

PS: your body text says $X+Y=10$ where as the title said $X+Y=11$. So...